# Removing multiple markers from google maps API based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using ajax to receive a student list and placing markers using the following code:

```
           jQuery.each( data, function( key, val ) {    
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var color = $("select[name=color]", form).val();
                var address = val["address"];
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if(results){
                      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            icon: "../image/icons/map/icon_marker"+color+".png",
                            title: val["name"],
                            id:val['id'],
                            url: ""
                        });

                    }
                });

            });
```

Something to note, val['id'] is not a unique id for that student but an id tied to all markers placed in this way. I'm assuming this needs to be a class or something and not an id but I don't want to change it unless I know its right.

Is there a way to call each marker that has a given id and remove only those markers? I keep finding ways for all IDs or 1 ID at a time, neither of these methods meet my goals.

Comment: did you have a markers array or something where you store all the markers?

Comment: I can I guess I just don't understand how... Are there id's associated with each array? Is it as simple as giving them each a tag with "1" as an Id then deleted every marker that has the tag "1"?

Comment: you can have something like `var markers = []` and when you add a new marker make this `markers.push(marker)`. and now based on that we can make some validation to remove markers

Comment: How would I go and call a specific set of marker out of that to delete? Would it be like this? var removeMarkers = markers[someKey]; removeMarkers.setMap(null);

Answer (score 0):

Create a MVCObject and set a property with a name equal to the `id` and the map as value.

```
//outside of $.each()
if(!students){
 students=new google.maps.MVCObject();
}

//inside of $.each()
if(!students.get(val['id'])){
  students.set(val['id'],map);
}
```

after the creation of the marker bind the `map`-property of the marker to the particular item of `students`:

```
marker.bindTo('map', students, val['id']);
```

and add a `map_changed`-listener for the `marker` to `unbind` the `map`-property when it will be set to `null` :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function () {
  if (!this.getMap()) {
    this.unbind('map');
  }
});
```

to remove all markers with a particular `id` simply call:

```
students.set('theId',null);
```

The advantage compared with an array-based approach: especially when you have a lot of markers you don't have to iterate over all these markers and check the id's

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/smo8eob2/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/smo8eob2/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of Ethaan in a chatroom. He helped me get to where I could see the problem!

Anyway here is the code that I have working properly. The id:val['id'] I've passed to each of the markers is the name of the form it is connected to... So I am just looping through all markers and removing the ones that are tied to the given id...I wish it didn't have to be a loop and could just be a "remove all where id = "form" but it works for now!

```
$("input[name=deleteLayer]").click(function(){
    //Get the name of the form that the button "deleteLayer" belongs to
    var formName = $(this).closest("form").attr('name');
    for(var $x = 0; $x < markersArray.length; $x++){
        //markersArray is an array that holds all the markers
        if(markersArray[$x]["id"] == formName){
            var removeMarkers = markersArray[$x];
            removeMarkers.setMap(null);
        }
    }
});
```